# Cant calculate derivative wrt any float with sympy

Tags: python, sympy, diff

Im sure once I post this Ill get referenced to every StackOverflow question that has been asked about this, but from all of my digging, I swear I could not find an answer to this.

I cannot seem to get sympy's `diff()` to work. It either refuses to actually try to differentiate the expression, or it spits out that `Cant calculate derivative wrt` error.

My code so far:

```py
x = np.arange(0, np.pi * 2, 0.1)

slope = diff(np.cos(x), x)
```

(I would like to point out that I have more code than this, but I have isolated this as the problem section. Also yes, I do have both of those libraries imported and loaded)

When I run that bit, it throws a `Cant calculate derivative wrt 1.00000000000000`. So my next thought was "maybe its trying to calculate the derivative with respect to the value of the variable, and not the actual variable itself", so I removed the `x = np.arange(0, np.pi * 2, 0.1)` bit, but of course python said the variable is undefined. So, I just gave it a single value of 0, but then it said that the `First variable cannot be a number: 0` (and yes, if I change the value, it just changes the value given in the error).

So as a last resort attempt, I decided to try `slope = diff(np.cos(x), 'x')`, and surprisingly, that seemed to work. But when I tried to get it to display what "slope" was actually equal to, it just said 0, which is obviously incorrect.

So at this point, I don't know what to do. Ive spent like 5 hours scouring the internet. All of the docs and tutorials show I have it all correctly written, yet that's obviously not true. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here. Please help me, or suggest any other ways of taking derivatives (ideally symbolically).

---

Edit: I implemented Oscar's tip and it worked for the test portion I had set up, but once I started integrating it with my code, it broke down again, this time resulting in a `'ImmutableDenseNDimArray' object has no attribute 'as_coefficient'` error.

My code:

```py
x=np.arange(-np.pi,np.pi,0.01)
n = 127
for i in np.arange(0,n):
  an = quad(fc,-np.pi,np.pi)[0] * (1.0/np.pi)
  An.append(an)

for i in np.arange(0,n):
  bn=quad(fs,-np.pi,np.pi)[0]*(1.0/np.pi)
  Bn.append(bn) #putting value in array Bn

for i in np.arange(0,n):
  if i==0.0:
    symsum += f'An[{i}] / 2'
  else:
    symsum += f' + (An[{i}] * cos({i} * x) + Bn[{i}] * sin({i} * x))'

print(symsum)
sumf = lambda x: eval(symsum)
sum = sumf(x) #<--error here
ranger = x
x = Symbol('x')
dersymsum = f'{diff(eval(symsum), x)}'
print(dersymsum)
```

My tests have shown that evaluating a string in a lambda function does result in a workable function that I normally can evaluate over the range that is x, using the same `np.arange` function, over the same `-np.pi` to `np.pi` range. Also, if I remove the conversion of symsum to sum portion, and just evaluate the derivative, it works, but then if I put the portion back in, but evaluate it after the derivation has occurred, over 'ranger' instead of 'x', it returns the same error. Sorry for bugging you guys, but I dont know what to do. In my eyes, there is no np function that the function is being evaluated over (since the `np.arange` should only refer to the range it made)

Comment: Have you actually read the `sympy` docs?  Start with the `tutorial` https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/index.html#tutorial   Don't mix `numpy` and `sympy` until you are an expert in both!  `np.cos(x)` is not a `sympy` expression.  It is a numpy function call that returns a number or array.  Spend more time with the official documentation, and less 'scouring the internet`.

Comment: The code is incomplete and doesn't run at all. Rather than changing the question please ask a new question and either make it a very specific question or explain what you are actually trying to do. Also as suggested in the comment above it seems likely that you might get a lot more benefit than just the answer to your immediate question if you spend time reading the sympy tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a *symbolic* derivative then NumPy plays no part in this:

```
In [7]: import sympy

In [8]: x = sympy.Symbol('x')

In [9]: sympy.diff(sympy.cos(x), x)
Out[9]: -sin(x)
```

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/intro.html#what-is-symbolic-computation

Comment: Possibly `from numpy import *` at the root of this?

Comment: This originally worked, but once i started to integrate other bits of code, it broke again, this time with the error ```'ImmutableDenseNDimArray' object has no attribute 'as_coefficient'```.  I would like to say that I have already converted all np.cos and np.sin functions to sympy. See edit above for full code.